# .bash_profile command arguments

Tags: bash, unix

I was looking for a redhat Tree command workaround and keep finding this specifically

```
alias lst='ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e '"'"'s/:$//'"'"' -e '"'"'s/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g'"'"' -e '"'"'s/^/   /'"'"' -e '"'"'s/-/|/'"'"
```

I'm trying to add files to the output tree and I have no idea what any of this is saying, could someone tell me what this command is saying and how to add to it?

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are generally too broad to be within our topic rules. See [How to handle "explain how this code dump works" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta]. "How to add to it" is even more nebulous/poorly defined. What modifications are you trying to make? What have you tried, what did you want it to do, and exactly  what did it do instead?

Comment: BTW, the command in question would be **vastly** easier to work with / modify if it were written as a function instead of an alias. `lst() { ls -R | grep ':$' | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'; }` is the exact same command, but written as a function instead.

Comment: ...btw, I got that decomposition by running `set -x` to enable logging, and then executing the alias. `set -x` is generally a thing it's worth keeping handy in your toolbox. :)